# цикл for в Python, простой вопрос

Tags: python

```
for х in ["spam”, "eggs”, "ham”]:
    ...
    print(x, end=’ ’)
```

результат: `spam eggs ham`

И зачем все это делалось если можно просто через принт их провести? Умоляю, человеческим языком объясните что и зачем это нужно.

Нашел на оф.сайте Питона:
for loops are traditionally used when you have a block of code which you want to repeat a fixed number of times. The Python for statement iterates over the members of a sequence in order, executing the block each time. Contrast the for statement with the ''while'' loop, used when a condition needs to be checked each iteration, or to repeat a block of code forever

Comment: Чтобы вывести элементы через пробел, а не через запятую. Я так думаю :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном примере действительно непонятно, для чего тут цикл, однако существуют более сложные случаи, когда нужно, например, фильтровать данные перед выводом.

Comment: Ну как для новичка мне это знать пока необязательно, верно? Обойдусь просто знанием данного цикла?

Comment: @ЭдуардВан в общем да. Чтобы получить тот же вывод можно использовать распаковку: `print(*my_list, sep=' ')`, где `my_list` список, который нужно вывести